# I just wanted to concatenate two strings in java

Tags: java

I have just started learning java and written a very bad code.I'm pretty sure there would be better way to write the code. Can anyone explain me why this code giving me the output : "nullnull"

```
public class Hello {

    public String a;
    public String b;
    public String c;

    public Hello() {
        c = "";
    }

    public String helloWorld() {
        return c;
    }

    public String hello() {
        a = "Hello";
        return a;
    }

    public String world() {
        b = "World";
        return b;
    }

    public void join() {
        c = a + b;
    }
}
```

Comment: looks like you called join method before calling other methods. Show us full codes

Comment: This code wouldn't give you any output at all. You're not calling any methods, unless there is a `main` that you haven't posted.

Comment: `join()` must be called after actually setting the values, which, in your case, is most likely not done.

Comment: Where is your  `static void main` where you call the join method?

Comment: Nor is there any code to actually output anything.

Comment: How are you using this class, Provide your calling class code.

Comment: Hint: https://ideone.com/UFZsMX

Comment: I'm using DrJava so I don't need main method just yet, I can call this function manually. {I start with Hello d= new Hello();} {g.join();} {g.helloWorld();} give me output "nullnull"

Comment: What do you think are the values of `a` and `b` before calling `hello()` and `world()`? And this is what you currently do. You call `join()` before setting `a` and `b`.

Comment: Still gets the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DrJava you need to call the methods in the following order:

- Hello d = new hello();
- d.hello();
- d.world();
- d.join();
- d.helloWorld();

or modify the helloWorld function to:

```
public String helloWorld() {
    hello();
    world();
    join();
    return c;
}
```

The a and b strings are not yet set (because you set them in `hello()` and `world()`) therefore when you call `join()`, they are still a null value.

Comment: Thanks mate, that just worked without changing my code.

Comment: Thats just the perfect example of calling instances of class within the same class. Your answer helped me to understand the concept. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple solution

```
package com.fred.code;

public class concat {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = "hello";
        String b = "world";
        System.out.println(a + b);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I just wanted to explore how the instance of class works within the class.